# Angular : ngx-echart 5.2.2 integration with Angular 9 ERR : NG8002: Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular, typescript

Good Day!
I am trying to implement a line cart in **Angular 9** using **ngx-echarts 5.2.2** as it was the recommended version in npm. While running `ng serve -o` I am getting the error: `NG8002: Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.` The code can be found over here [Github repo](https://github.com/Linux-Maniac/front-end-dev/tree/main/angular-chart-poc)

> The **HTML template** for the **transaction-fee-line-chart.component.ts** is :

```
<div echarts [options]="_chartOption"></div>
```

> The **Component file : transaction-fee-line-chart.component.ts** is:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import { EChartsOption } from 'echarts';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { GetTransactionyChannelName_Req } from 'src/app/models/getTransactionByChannelName.model';
import { TransactionFeeDetail } from 'src/app/models/getTransactionByChannelName.model';
import { GetTransactionFeeByChannelNameService } from 'src/app/services/get-transaction-fee-by-channel-name.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-transaction-fee-line-chart',
  templateUrl: './transaction-fee-line-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./transaction-fee-line-chart.component.css']
})
export class TransactionFeeLineChartComponent implements OnInit {
  _chartOption : EChartsOption;
  subscription : Subscription;

  constructor(private service: GetTransactionFeeByChannelNameService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("Preparing line chart");    
    let req_getTransactionFeeByChannelName = new GetTransactionyChannelName_Req();

    req_getTransactionFeeByChannelName.channelName = 'XYZ';
    req_getTransactionFeeByChannelName.fromDate = '01/01/2023';
    req_getTransactionFeeByChannelName.toDate = '31/05/2023';

    this.subscription=this.service.getTransactionFeeByChannelName(req_getTransactionFeeByChannelName)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        console.log(`API Resp : ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);        
        this._initChartTransactionFeeByChannelName(response.transactions);
      });
  }

  private _initChartTransactionFeeByChannelName(chartData : TransactionFeeDetail[]){
    this._chartOption={
      tooltip : {
        show : true,
      },
      background : 'transparent',
      xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: chartData.map(m=>m.transactionType)
      },
      yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
      },
      series: [
        {
          data: chartData.map(m=>m.totalFee),
          type: 'line'
        }
      ]
    };

  }
}
```

The **Service code : get-transaction-fee-by-channel-name.service.ts**  calls an external API whose response is :

```
{
   "success": true,
   "transactions":    [
            {
         "transactionType": "Transaction-1",
         "totalFee": 322.1,
         "isFeetoCustomer": "Y"
      },
            {
         "transactionType": "Transaction-2",
         "totalFee": 18704.58,
         "isFeetoCustomer": "Y"
      },
            {
         "transactionType": "Transaction-3",
         "totalFee": 6234.860000000001,
         "isFeetoCustomer": "N"
      }
   ]
}
```

> Attaching screenshot of the error for reference :
> [image]

> Angular and Node versions are : [image]

Since the code is to be merged with a legacy project I cannot change the Angular version. Would appreciate any help in this regard.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you added the appropriate entity to the imports?
Try to add NgxEchartsDirective to imports in your your-component.module.ts

Comment: Hi @SviatoslavMiller thanks for the response. I have imported **NgxEchartsModule** in **app.module.ts**, should I import **NgxEchartsDirective** as well in the same file?

Comment: Have you separate module for transaction-fee-line-chart component?

Comment: I do not have a separate module for the component. I generated the component files using `ng g component` so no component module was generated. I have shared the code repo link in the post, could you kindly check it once if my understanding is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `TransactionFeeLineChartComponent` component to the imports array, that might be the root cause of your issue! When we use a component in routing, it has to be added to the `declarations` array of the module where the routing is defined!

As per the [documentation](https://xieziyu.github.io/ngx-echarts/#/welcome) we need to imports the module `NgxEchartsModule` differently!

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TransactionFeeLineChartComponent,     
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgxEchartsModule.forRoot({
      echarts: () => import('echarts')
    }),
  ],
  providers: [GetTransactionFeeByChannelNameService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```